# How can i change multiple same values with other in list?

Tags: vb.net, linq, list

I have a list

```
          List1 = {"abc", "abc", "dfg", "abc"}
```

i want change all "abc" values with "cde"

```
          List1 = {"cde", "cde", "dfg", "cde"}
```

How can i change them with linq?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use the `Select` method to check each member of the list and replace it. The following gives the result you expect.

```
Dim List1 As New List(Of String) From {"abc", "abc", "dfg", "abc"}    
List1 = List1.Select(Function(s) If(s = "abc", "cde", s)).ToList
```

If List1 is actually an array rather than a List, the method is similar.

```
Dim List1() As String = {"abc", "abc", "dfg", "abc"}
List1 = List1.Select(Function(s) If(s = "abc", "cde", s)).ToArray
```